# I am unable to export my Python ouput to an excel file

Tags: python, excel, selenium, beautifulsoup

I wrote the following code and I am unable to export the data to an excel sheet.

```
from selenium import webdriver 
import time, re
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd 

chrome_path = r"C:\Users\user\Desktop\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)

driver.get("http://agmarknet.gov.in/PriceTrends/SA_Pri_Month.aspx")

html_source = driver.page_source


for x in range(1,6): #loop for 5 months
    print (x)
    element_commodity = driver.find_element_by_id ("cphBody_Commodity_list")
    drp_commodity = Select(element_commodity)
    drp_commodity.select_by_visible_text("Wheat")

    time.sleep(15)

    element_year = driver.find_element_by_id ("cphBody_Year_list")
    drp_year = Select(element_year)

    drp_year.select_by_visible_text("2020")

    time.sleep(15)

    element_month = driver.find_element_by_id ("cphBody_Month_list")
    drp_month = Select(element_month)

   drp_month.select_by_index(x)
   time.sleep(15)

    driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="cphBody_But_Submit"]""").click()
    time.sleep(15)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
    table = pd.read_html(driver.page_source)[3] #third table is the one that we want
    print(len(table))
    print(table)

    table.to_excel(r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\python.xlsx', sheet_name = 'x')
```

And this is the output that I am getting:

```
   1
   18
             0  ...                             5
   0            State  ...  % Change(Over Previous Year)
   1            Assam  ...                            __
   2      Chattisgarh  ...                        -36.87
   3          Gujarat  ...                          6.73
   4          Haryana  ...                            __
   5        Jharkhand  ...                            __
   6        Karnataka  ...                         -1.82
   7           Kerala  ...                         11.27
   8   Madhya Pradesh  ...                          7.46
   9      Maharashtra  ...                          1.46
   10    NCT of Delhi  ...                          5.05
   11          Odisha  ...                            __
   12          Punjab  ...                            __
   13       Rajasthan  ...                          8.12
   14   Uttar Pradesh  ...                           8.5
   15      Uttrakhand  ...                          2.83
   16     West Bengal  ...                          5.69
   17         Average  ...                           NaN

   [18 rows x 6 columns]
  2
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\agmarknet soup table extraction 
  trial.py", line 17, in <module>
element_commodity = driver.find_element_by_id ("cphBody_Commodity_list")
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 360, in find_element_by_id
return self.find_element(by=By.ID, value=id_)
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site- 
packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 976, in find_element
return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site- 
packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site- 
packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate 
element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="cphBody_Commodity_list"]"}
(Session info: chrome=83.0.4103.61)
```

The idea was to create an excel file with 5 sheets corresponding to the output from 5 months in the dropdown menu. I am unable to understand why the .to_excel command is not working. Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few issues:

1. With every loop the webpage generates the results, but the initial
   search criteria panel is no longer there, hence
   `NoSuchElementException` you see. A quick fix for that is to add a `driver.back()` as the last action inside the loop.
2. The way to write dataframes to multiple Excel sheets is a bit more
   complex than that.

I have made some changes to your script to address these issues. The logic is to store all collected tables in a `results` list, then write this list to Excel, each table on a separate worksheet.

```
results=[]
for x in range(1,6): #loop for 5 months
    print (x)
    element_commodity = driver.find_element_by_id ("cphBody_Commodity_list")
    drp_commodity = Select(element_commodity)
    drp_commodity.select_by_visible_text("Wheat")

    time.sleep(10)

    element_year = driver.find_element_by_id ("cphBody_Year_list")
    drp_year = Select(element_year)

    drp_year.select_by_visible_text("2020")

    time.sleep(10)

    element_month = driver.find_element_by_id ("cphBody_Month_list")
    drp_month = Select(element_month)

    drp_month.select_by_index(x)
    time.sleep(10)

    driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="cphBody_But_Submit"]""").click()
    time.sleep(10)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
    table = pd.read_html(driver.page_source)[3] #third table is the one that we want
    print(len(table))
    print(table)

    results.append(table)

    driver.back()
    time.sleep(1)

with pd.ExcelWriter(r'eexport_sheets.xlsx') as writer:
    for i, table in enumerate(results):
        table.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = f'{i+1}', index=False)
    writer.save()
```

**Excel Output:**
[image]

**General note** - consider using `WebdriverWait` instead of `time.sleep`.

Comment: Thank you so much, the code runs perfectly now! Also a great tip about WebdriverWait. The command is very useful. Thank you so much!

Comment: No worries. Whenever comfortable with an answer, please mark it as Accepted.